# Posting an array from view to controller using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

```
function myItemsViewModel(ItemID, GroupID, ItemName, Quantity) {
this.ItemID = ItemID;
this.GroupID = GroupID;
this.ItemName = ItemName;
this.Quantity = Quantity;
```

}

And i have below code for posting to the controller

```
 var CreateRecord = function () {
    var Name = $.trim($("#divCreate").find("#txtName").val());
    var Department  = $.trim($("#divCreate").find("#txtDepartment").val());

    var ItemsList = [];
    $('#myDynamicTable').find('tr').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var itemName = $.trim(row.find(".itemName input").val());
        var itemQty = $.trim(row.find(".itemQty input").val());

        var myItems = new myItemsViewModel("", "", itemName, itemQty);
        ItemsList.push(myItems);
    });

    var obj = new myRecordEntryViewModel("", Name, Department, ItemsList);
    var viewmodel = JSON.stringify(obj);    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: viewmodel,
                    headers: GetRequestVerificationToken(),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: '/' + virtualDirectory + '/RecordEntry/Save',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#divMaster").html(data);
                        return false;
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert("Error Submitting Record Request!");
                    }
                });
            }
```

At the line `var viewmodel = JSON.stringify(obj);`, viewmodel has all the values that i want in my `ItemsList` array variable.

Problem is my ItemsList array is coming as null in the controller. Name and Department are coming through with the correct passed values.

Below is my controller code.

**Class**

```
 public class myRecordEntryViewModel 
    {
        public  long ID { get; set; }
        public  string Name { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string[] ItemsList { get; set; }
    }
```

**Save action**

```
    [ActionName("Save")]
    [NoCache]
    public ActionResult Save(myRecordEntryViewModel viewModel)
    {
            //here viewModel.ItemsList is null, what could i be missing
            if (this.SaveEntry(viewModel.Name,viewModel.Department,viewModel.ItemsList))
            {

            }
        return this.View();
    }
```

I'm wondering why `viewModel.ItemsList` is coming as null in controller yet it has values during the post from jQuery.

Comment: `ItemsList` in your model is `string[]` but you script appears to be generating an array of javascript objects containing multiple properties (what is `myItemsViewModel`?)

Comment: Can you show the JSON string of the view model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i have edited my post to add "myItemsViewModel"

Comment: So is `public string[] ItemsList` correct? - you cant post an array of complex objects to `string[]`.

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior. If you change `ItemsList` to `var ItemsList = [ 'abc', 'def' ];` and add `traditional: true,` to the ajax options, you will see that you model is correctly bound. Otherwise you need to change `ItemsList` to `IEnumerable<ItemsModel>` where `ItemsModel` contains the 4 properties in `myItemsViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class for the Item in Item List (In C#)

```
public class Item {
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And then change the viewmodel class

```
 public class myRecordEntryViewModel 
{
    public  long ID { get; set; }
    public  string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    //public string[] ItemsList { get; set; }
    public List<Item> ItemsList {get ; set;}
}
```

The controller can not map the Item List from your request into model because one is a list of string and other is a list of object.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your codes...

1) ItemList in your class and your javascript code are not same - The frist one is an array of strings, and the second is an array of objects

2) In your action method, you should change parameter type like the following:

```
public ActionResult Save(string viewModel)
```

3) In the body of your action method, you should deserialize the json string (viewModel) and make the model object from it. The following is an example...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17741421/1814343

Comment: dataType: specifies the data that is returned from the method, and the method returns a view (i.e. html). OP has a model so why on earth would you bind to a string. The `DefaultModelBinder` takes care of all this for you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh yeah you're right. It was my mistake about dataType and contentType. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and see if your model gets the values. 
**Let me know if you face any problems, because I've already implemented this in one of my projects**

```
var CreateRecord = function () {
    var Name = $.trim($("#divCreate").find("#txtName").val());
    var Department  = $.trim($("#divCreate").find("#txtDepartment").val());
    var model="";
    var ItemsList = [];
    $('#myDynamicTable').find('tr').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var itemName = $.trim(row.find(".itemName input").val());
        var itemQty = $.trim(row.find(".itemQty input").val());

        var myItems = new myItemsViewModel("", "", itemName, itemQty);
        ItemsList.push(myItems);
    });
    model = ['Name' : Name , 'Department' : Department , 'ItemsList' :ItemsList];
       $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: JSON.stringify(model),
                    headers: GetRequestVerificationToken(),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: '/' + virtualDirectory + '/RecordEntry/Save',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#divMaster").html(data);
                        HideLoader();
                        return false;
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert("Error Submitting Record Request!");
                        HideLoader();
                    }
                });
            }
```